# Reading a large file in functional scala

Tags: java, scala, file-io

I'm attempting to process a large binary file with scala. If possible I'd like to use a functional approach. My main method for this looks like this right now:

```
def getFromBis( buffer:List[Byte], bis:BufferedInputStream ):(Byte,List[Byte],Boolean) = {
    buffer match {
        case Nil =>
            val buffer2 = new Array[Byte](100000)
            bis.read(buffer2) match {
                case -1 => (-1,Nil,false)
                case _  => 
                    val buffer3 = buffer2.toList
                    (buffer3.head,buffer3.tail,true)
            }
        case b::tail => return (b,tail,true)
    }
}
```

It takes a list buffer and a buffered input stream. If the buffer isn't empty it simply returns the head and tail, if it is empty it gets the next chunk from the file and uses that as the buffer instead.

As you can see this isn't very functional. I'm trying to do this in a way where there's as few underlying io calls as possible, which is why I'm doing this in a chunked fashion. The problem here is the new Array. Everytime I run through the function it creates a new array, and judging by the constantly increasing memory usage as the program runs, I don't think they're getting destroyed.

My question is this: Is there a better way to be reading a large file in a chunked fashion using scala? I'd like to keep a completely functional approach, but at the very least I need a function which could act as a black box for the rest of my functional program.

Comment: [This post](http://www.jayconrod.com/posts/27/processing-large-files-in-scala) about processing big files in events-stream-like-style could help you.
It is quite old, but I think is still good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want to store bytes in a `List`.  You need a new object for each byte.  That's really inefficient, and will cause probably 20x more memory usage than you need.

The easiest way to do this is to create an iterator that stores internal state:

```
class BisReader(bis: BufferedInputStream) {
  val buffer = new Array[Byte](100000)
  var n = 0
  var i = 0
  def hasNext: Boolean = (i < n) || (n >= 0 && {
    n = bis.read(buffer)
    i = 0
    hasNext
  })
  def next: Byte = {
    if (i < n) {
      val b = buffer(i)
      i += 1
      b
    }
    else if (hasNext) next
    else throw new IOException("Input stream empty")
  }
}
implicit def reader_as_iterator(br: BisReader) = new Iterator[Byte] {
  def hasNext = br.hasNext
  def next = br.next
}
```

One could have BisReader extend Iterator[Byte], but since Iterator isn't specialized, this would require boxing for raw next/hasNext access.  This way, you can get low-level (next/hasNext) access at full speed when you need it, and use handy iterator methods otherwise.

Now you've isolated your ugly nonfunctional Java IO stuff in a single class with a clean interface, and can go back to being functional.

---

Edit: except, of course, IO is order-dependent and has side effects, but the previous method doesn't get around that either.

Comment: You are awesome, thank you! What I've been doing up till now is just sending that list of bytes around, taking the head off here and there, but I guess I can send around an index variable.

Comment: @Mediocre Gopher - Just send an instance of `BisReader` around, and grab an item with `next` when you need one.  You can--if you want maximal efficiency--create your own equivalent of `getOrElse`, too, so you don't have to worry about checking `hasNext` all the time.

Comment: Aren't you still boxing each Byte, or did iterator get the specialization treatment?

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - If you use `Iterator[Byte]` it's boxed.  If you use `BisReader` it just _looks_ like an iterator but is using primitives.  The implicit wrapper, if needed, will go back to boxing, but at least you have a high-performance `hasNext` and `next`.

Comment: @Rex - you are right; I'd just assumed that your `BisReader` implemented `Iterator` when I read "iterator" in the answer.